# Call executables in the Windows folder from Jenkins shell step

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I would like to call MSBuild in Jenkins, in a shell step. Although from what I recall; you can access only the workspace folder, which is what is allowed in Jenkins.

How do you actually build in Windows environment, when using Jenkins, if your build tool is in `Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Although from what I recall; you can access only the workspace folder, which is what is allowed in Jenkins.

That is true for the source on which your command (here MSBuild) will operate on.

But the command itself can be called (from a build step) with its full path, even though said full path is outside the local workspace.

Or you can specify that installation path through the [Jenkins MSBuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/MSBuild+Plugin).

> To use this plugin, specify the location directory of `MSBuild.exe` on Jenkin's configuration page.
>   The MSBuild executable is usually situated in a subfolder of `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework`. If you have multiple MSBuild versions installed, you can configure multiple executables.
>
> Then, on your project configuration page, specify the name of the build file (`.proj` or `.sln`) and any command line
>   arguments you want to pass in. The files are compiled to the directory where Visual Studio would put them as well.